# android-annotation: error: cannot find symbol

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-annotations

in app/build.gradle:

```
def AAVersion = '4.5.2'

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"  
implementation "com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:2.7.1"
```

in gradle.properties:

```
android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true
```

and in my fragment:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.Background;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.EFragment;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.UiThread;

@EFragment
public class SelectAgentMainFragment extends WZRootFragment
        implements FragmentPagerPageSelectedListener, Serializable, LocationAware {
public static final String IS_HIDE_MAP_TAB = SelectAgentMainFragment_.class.getName() + "_IS_HIDE_MAP_TAB";
```

But I get compile error:

```
   > Task :mymodule1:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Gradle may disable incremental compilation as the following annotation processors are not incremental: androidannotations-4.5.2.jar (org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.5.2).
Consider setting the experimental feature flag android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true in the gradle.properties file to run annotation processing in a separate task and make compilation incremental.
mymodule1\src\main\java\android\agents\SelectAgentMainFragment.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
    public static final String IS_HIDE_MAP_TAB = SelectAgentMainFragment_.class.getName() + "_IS_HIDE_MAP_TAB";


                                                 ^
  symbol:   class SelectAgentMainFragment_
  location: class SelectAgentMainFragment
```

P.S.

```
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'false'.
```

Answer (score 0):

This code looks to have issue.

```
public static final String IS_HIDE_MAP_TAB = SelectAgentMainFragment_.class.getName() + "_IS_HIDE_MAP_TAB";
```

Change it to

```
public static final String IS_HIDE_MAP_TAB = SelectAgentMainFragment.class.getName() + "_IS_HIDE_MAP_TAB";
```

Comment: SelectAgentMainFragment_.class.getName() success work on Eclipse. But not work on Android Studio 3.4

Comment: I find solution: I must use org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.6.0 and implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-4.6.0"